Fiji Macro for .nd2 images batch processing
Can anybody tell me why with this macro I just get as an output for each channel of each image a .png file of the first image slice and not of the stacked image? It seems like the Z-project part of the code is not properly working, thanks in advance!!
`// Function to process each .nd2 file
function processFile(filePath) {
    // Open the .nd2 file
    setBatchMode(true);
    open(filePath);
    // Get the title of the opened image
    title = getTitle();
    
    // Stack different focal planes into one high projection image per channel
    run("Split Channels");
    channelTitles = getList("image.titles");

    // Process each channel
    for (c = 0; c < channelTitles.length; c++) {
        selectWindow(channelTitles[c]);
         // Get the total number of slices
        totalSlices = getSliceNumber();

        // Use all slices for Z Projection
        run("Z Project...", start=1 stop=totalSlices, " projection=[Max Intensity]");
        run("Update");
        projTitle = getTitle();
        close(channelTitles[c]);
        selectWindow(projTitle);
        // Adjust brightness and contrast automatically
        run("Enhance Contrast", "saturated=0.35");
        run("Update")
        run("Apply LUT", "stack");
        
        // Convert to RGB
        run("RGB Color");
        
        // Save the processed channel
        saveAs("Tiff", filePath + "_channel" + (c + 1) + ".tif");
        close();
    }
    
    // Close the original image
    close(title);
}`


I tried to work on the following portion of the code by selecting the project image once generated and closing the original one but it doesn't still work....
// Use all slices for Z Projection
        run("Z Project...", start=1 stop=totalSlices, " projection=[Max Intensity]");
        run("Update");
        projTitle = getTitle();
        close(channelTitles[c]);
        selectWindow(projTitle);

That is an example of how it should look like if I do the same passages listed in the code in Fiji directly on each image
That's what I get after all the attempt and suggestions you gave me

In order to provide substantial help, please explain in detail where you start from and what you like to obtain. Your code above doesn't help if you don't provide an exact description from what kind of images or stacks you are starting and what you like to save at the end of which kind of  processing.

Dear @Herbie I start from .nd2 images acquired at confocal microscope, I have different channels and for each of them I want to stack (Max projection method) and and adjust brightness/contrast to obtain a .png file. I run the pipeline as a macro in batch processing of Fiji...do you have any suggestion what it's going wrong?

For every colour-channel you want to do a max z-projection?(You write "I want to stack [Max projection method] but a max-projection gives you a single image not a stack. Please understand that we need a precise description!) Of course I have suggestions but I won't bother with your code, but code it independently. Could you please make available a small sample of your .nd2 data, perhaps via a dropbox-like service?

Before we really start with coding, I like to know, how you import your .nd2-files to ImageJ? I would import them using BioFormats-importer with split channels ticked to you get separate stacks for the colours, This can of course be done by a macro call.

Below please find an ImageJ demo macro that uses a ".nd2"-file I found here. Please download this raw-file and try the macro with this file! The file shows two colour-channels with four images (here: time points).
//imagej-macro "nd2-processing" (Herbie G., 09. Aug. 2024)
requires("1.54j");
path=File.openDialog("Open the sample nd2-file");
run("Bio-Formats","open=[path] color_mode=Default rois_import=[ROI manager] split_channels view=Hyperstack stack_order=XYCZT use_virtual_stack series_1");
path=File.getDirectory(path)+File.nameWithoutExtension;
clr=newArray("Blue","Green","Red");
n=nImages;
for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
   run("Z Project...","projection=[Max Intensity]");
   run("Enhance Contrast...","saturated=0.35");
   run(clr[i]);
   saveAs("PNG",path+"_ch-"+(n-i)+".png");
   close(); close();
}
exit();
//imagej-macro "nd2-processing" (Herbie G., 09. Aug. 2024)

Please note that by assigning a LUT to the projection images makes them saved with 8bit depth. Save in TIF-format to keep the 16bit depth.
=============================================
Finally, below please find the code for batch processing all ".nd2"-files in a folder:
//imagej-macro "batch_nd2-processing" (Herbie G., 09./10. Aug. 2024)
requires("1.54j");
close("*");
inSfx=2;  // preferred source file suffix
outSfx=0; // preferred result file suffix
Dialog.create("Batch Process Folder");
   sfxIn=newArray(".tif",".czi",".nd2");
   sfxOut=newArray(".tif",".png",".jpg");
   Dialog.setInsets(0,220,0);
   Dialog.addMessage("Macro does not process nested folders!",12,"blue");
   Dialog.setInsets(6,0,0);
   Dialog.addChoice("Suffix",sfxIn,sfxIn[inSfx]);   
   Dialog.setInsets(-28,182,0);
   Dialog.addMessage("of the source files");   
   Dialog.addDirectory("Source-Folder",getDir("file"));
   Dialog.addChoice("Suffix",sfxOut,sfxOut[outSfx]);   
   Dialog.setInsets(-37,182,0);
   Dialog.addMessage("for the result files");  
   Dialog.addDirectory("Result-Folder",getDir("file"));
Dialog.show();
sfx1=Dialog.getChoice();
srce=Dialog.getString();
sfx2=Dialog.getChoice();
dest=Dialog.getString();
setBatchMode(true);
count=processFolder(sfx1,srce,sfx2,dest);
setBatchMode(false);
exit(""+count+" files processed");
//
function processFolder(xtn1,dir1,xtn2,dir2) {
   color=newArray("Blue","Green","Red","Yellow","Magenta","Cyan");
   cnt=0;
   list=getFileList(dir1);
   n=list.length;
   for (i=0;i<n;i++)
      if (endsWith(list[i],xtn1)) {
         path=dir1+list[i];
         run("Bio-Formats","open=[path] color_mode=Default split_channels view=Hyperstack stack_order=XYCZT use_virtual_stack series_1");
         path=dir2+File.nameWithoutExtension;
         Stack.getDimensions(w,h,c,s,f);
         if (s>1||f>1) {
            cnt++;
            processStack(path,xtn2,color);
         } else {
            close("*");
            print("Unsuited image data: "+list[i]);
         }
      }
   return cnt;
}
function processStack(pth,xtn,clr) {
   n=nImages;
   for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
      run("Z Project...","projection=[Max Intensity]");
      run("Enhance Contrast...","saturated=0.35");
      if (n<7) run(clr[i]);
      saveAs(pth+"_ch-"+(n-i)+xtn);
      close(); close();
   }
}
//imagej-macro "batch_nd2-processing" (Herbie G., 09./10. Aug. 2024)

It is assumed that the source stacks have a maximum of six colour channels!

This code seem at least to make the Z-stack properly, however I have problems to save the .png file once generated, additionally Fiji asks me everytime to select each .nd2 file individually, how can I set it up in a loop for a batch processing of all the files in a folder? Thanks in advance!

"problems to save the .png file once generated"; Please tell me what this means. My macro saves the PNG-files to the same directory the stacks come from. For batch-processing you need to call the essential parts of my macro from a loop. The code you have posted doesn't show this loop, so I assumed that you know how to do this. It is really difficult to help if you don't provide the necessary information in time.

I mean that when i ran the macro Fiji shows an error that can't save the .png file because it doesn't find the path (even though I specified it as you did in your macro). Maybe can you please write here the exact code that should work if I copy and paste it in Fiji-->process--> batch--> macro? maybe in this way it's more clear for me what I should exactly tell him to make it work. Thanks in advance!

Sorry but my posted code works as described, i.e. it saves the PNG-file correctly. I have no experience with "Fiji-->process--> batch--> macro" because I always code the outer batch-loop according to this example code "Help >> Examples >> Macro >> Process Folder".

Dear @Herbie Thank you! It's properly working now!!

Please check my previous answer that now also contains code for batch-processing.

The syntax for this line:
run("Z Project...", start=1 stop=totalSlices, " projection=[Max Intensity]");
is incorrect.
If you do:
run("Z Project...", "projection=[Max Intensity]");
it should run OK. The default is start at 1 and end at the last slice, so it will work.
To correct your original line (and understand why it wasn't working) you would need to do:
run("Z Project...", "start=1 stop=" + totalSlices + " projection=[Max Intensity]");
You need to construct a string as an argument, which your original code didn't do. However, there is an additional problem: totalSlices variable is defined by getSliceNumber() which is the number of the current slice (1) and not the total number of slices. This is why the code is not working.
The correct code should be:
// Function to process each .nd2 file
function processFile(filePath) {
    // Open the .nd2 file
    setBatchMode(true);
    open(filePath);
    // Get the title of the opened image
    title = getTitle();
    
    // Stack different focal planes into one high projection image per channel
    run("Split Channels");
    channelTitles = getList("image.titles");

    // Process each channel
    for (c = 0; c < channelTitles.length; c++) {
        selectWindow(channelTitles[c]);
        // Use all slices for Z Projection
        run("Z Project...", "projection=[Max Intensity]");
        projTitle = getTitle();
        close(channelTitles[c]);
        selectWindow(projTitle);
        // Adjust brightness and contrast automatically
        run("Enhance Contrast", "saturated=0.35");
        run("Apply LUT", "stack");
        
        // Convert to RGB
        run("RGB Color");
        
        // Save the processed channel
        saveAs("Tiff", filePath + "_channel" + (c + 1) + ".tif");
        close();
    }
    
    // Close the original image
    close(title);
}

Additionally, Bio-Formats Importer should be set so that opening each .nd2 file doesn't trigger the import dialog.

Thanks @quantixed! I tried to correct that line of the code but still the output I get (.png figure after running the batch processing of multiple .nd2 files in a specified input folder) it's like just the first Z-stack of each channel and not the stacked projection. I tested different attempts and scripts I found online but none of these works, any idea?

Would you mind answering my request above? If we don't know exactly what kind off images or stacks you like to process and how and exactly with which kind of result, we can't help

I've edited my answer above to explain why I think you are still not getting the desired output. The run("Update"); calls are also not needed and cause an error when I run the code. If you switch to my suggested change run("Z Project...", "projection=[Max Intensity]"); I think it will work.

@quantixed I tested the new code changing it as you suggested, but it doesn't seem to work still...I added an example of the images I get with the pipeline or doing the same procedure directly in Fiji for each image (see question images I attached to be more clear)....

I edited my answer again. This time it shows the full function. I've checked that it works with a 3 channel z-stack in nd2 format. Perhaps the changes you made didn't reflect what I was suggesting.

So if I copy and paste the last version of your code @quantixed my problem still persist, somehow it's not working the Z stacking of the focal planes, and I can see this by saving a .tif file that show me once I open it each focal plane of the image for each channel all in one file. I don't know why for you it's working but not for me
